# adminlte select 2 is not working in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to convert adminlte theme into reactjs

everything is working fine but when I use multi-select (select 2), my script is not loading until i will reload that page

my index.html page from public folder

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
      <meta
         name="description"
         content="Web site created using create-react-app"
         />
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
      <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
      <link
         rel="stylesheet"
         href="%PUBLIC_URL%/plugins/select2/css/select2.min.css"
         />
      <link
         rel="stylesheet"
         href="%PUBLIC_URL%/plugins/select2-bootstrap4-theme/select2-bootstrap4.min.css"
         />
      <link
         rel="stylesheet"
         href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700&display=fallback"
         />
      <link
         rel="stylesheet"
         href="%PUBLIC_URL%/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css"
         />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/dist/css/adminlte.min.css" />
      <!-- for data tables -->
      <link
         rel="stylesheet"
         href="%PUBLIC_URL%/plugins/datatables-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css"
         />
      <link
         rel="stylesheet"
         href="%PUBLIC_URL%/plugins/datatables-responsive/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css"
         />
      <link
         rel="stylesheet"
         href="%PUBLIC_URL%/plugins/datatables-buttons/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css"
         />
      <title>admin lte</title>
      <style type="text/css">
         .radio-button {
         font-size: 0;
         display: inline-block;
         position: relative;
         border: 4px solid #007bff;
         }
         .radio-button input[type="radio"] {
         margin: auto;
         visibility: hidden;
         position: absolute;
         left: 0;
         right: 0;
         bottom: 0;
         top: 0;
         }
         .radio-button label {
         color: #fff;
         background: #fff;
         font-size: 16px;
         line-height: 16px;
         font-weight: 400;
         text-align: center;
         width: 40px;
         padding: 0px;
         margin: 0;
         cursor: pointer;
         position: relative;
         z-index: 1;
         transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
         }
         .radio-button label:before {
         content: "";
         background: #007bff;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         opacity: 1;
         transform: scaleX(0);
         transform-origin: left center;
         position: absolute;
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
         z-index: -1;
         transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
         }
         .radio-button label:nth-child(2):before {
         transform-origin: right center;
         }
         .radio-button input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
         color: #fff;
         font-weight: normal;
         }
         .radio-button input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
         opacity: 1;
         transform: scaleX(1);
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body className="hold-transition sidebar-mini">
      <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
      <div id="root"></div>
      <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
      <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
      <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
      <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/plugins/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
      <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
      <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/plugins/datatables-responsive/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
      <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
      <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
      <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/plugins/jszip/jszip.min.js"></script>
      <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/plugins/pdfmake/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
      <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/plugins/pdfmake/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
      <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
      <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
      <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/plugins/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
      <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/plugins/select2/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(function () {
           $(".select2").select2();
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

My Component where I am calling multi-select

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";


export default function TeamComponent() {

 
  return (
    <div className="content-wrapper">
    
 
      {/* Main content */}
      <section className="content">
        {/* Default box */}
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-body row">
          
            <div classname="col-4">
              <div className="form-group">
                <label>User Id</label>
                <select
                  className="select2"
                  multiple="multiple"
                  data-placeholder="Select a State"
                  style={{ width: "100%" }}
                >
                  <option>Alabama</option>
                  <option>Alaska</option>
                  <option>California</option>
                  <option>Delaware</option>
                  <option>Tennessee</option>
                  <option>Texas</option>
                  <option>Washington</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      
      </section>
     
    </div>
  );
}
```

currently, my output is something like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kv5Ql.png)

when I hard refresh the page

then output is :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0WsI.png)

please help me and let me know how can I fix this problem

Comment: Try moving all the `sscript` tags above the React app you are trying to render.

Comment: still not working

Comment: I see. Have you tried a non-jquery solution? Jquery and React don't generally mix well at all. In `TeamComponent` component, use a mounting `useEffect` hook to access the DOM and attach or do whatever it is that `$(".select2").select2();` does.